# Control third-party Cast session from Android?

Tags: android, chromecast

I want to observe and control a Chromecast session that was started by another app.

When connecting using `MediaRouter`, however, I cannot join an ongoing session without disrupting it. As soon as I select a route, my app replaces the previous one.

How can I monitor a Chromecast session using the Android SDK (and be able to play, pause, see progress, etc), without replacing the receiver app that is currently playing?

Comment: Can you share your (best) implementation? Maybe it is something as simple as a wrong parameter.

Comment: I solved the problem by using the lower-level (deprecated) Cast API v2, which has much finer access and does not kill the currently playing application when it connects. This is the API `CastContext` uses under the hood. I'll answer my own question with the code when it's ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First Option:

You can use a [RemotePlaybackClient](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarouter#remote-playback)

> **Controlling a remote playback route**
>
> When you select a remote playback route your app acts as a remote
>   control. The device at the other end of the route handles all content
>   data retrieval, decoding, and playback functions. The controls in your
>   app's UI communicate with the receiver device using a
>   RemotePlaybackClient object.

[Javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/media/RemotePlaybackClient.html#top_of_page):

> **RemotePlaybackClient**
>
> A helper class for playing media on remote routes using the remote
>   playback protocol defined by MediaControlIntent.
>
> The client maintains session state and offers a simplified interface
>   for issuing remote playback media control intents to a single route.

You can create it with `RemotePlaybackClient(Context context, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route)`

You can check if the `MediaRouter.Route` supports remote requests by calling [`route.supportsControlCategory`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/media/MediaRouter.RouteInfo#supportscontrolcategory)

### Second Option:

If your app does not support this you can try managing through the [CastSession](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender/integrate#how_media_control_works). This way you app will communicate with the other app through the chromeecast. With [`CastSession.getRemoteMediaClient()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/CastSession.html#getRemoteMediaClient()) you get a [`RemoteMediaClient`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/RemoteMediaClient).

Comment: Tried that. At least with a direct approach, it throws `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The route does not support session management.`. Does it require additional initialization? Can I use it on a Route I have not "connected" to, when I don't control the receiver app?

Comment: You can check if the `MediaRouter` supports remote requests by calling [supportscontrolcategory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/media/MediaRouter.RouteInfo#supportscontrolcategory)

Comment: Update: the `RemotePlaybackClient`, created with the Chromecast route, does not support session management, remote playback or anything else. I cannot call any of its methods. I can connect perfectly using the `CastSession` API, but that stops the current receiver app

Comment: Are you sure that it is not the android os closing the other app and therefore stopping playback? Afaik connecting with `CastSession.getRemoteMediaClient()` does not stop playback.

Comment: `CastSession` automatically launches a new receiver application when connected to the Route (eg by selecting a route from the standard cast button dialog). This stops playback unless the application is the same.

Comment: I dont think it is possible to take over the session of an other app on the same device if it does not expose the proper media route hooks then.

Comment: (Sorry for this long conversation) But the Google Home app does this without a hitch. It's Google, though.

Comment: Maybe you can try and decompile it ;)

Comment: Haha if it gets to that, I'll probably give up. This was supposed to be fun. Thank you for your time, man :)

Comment: Forgot to accept this answer. I ended up with extremely complex life-cycle management of several related objects (so I get why they created the high-level API), but this was the way to get started. Maybe in some future I'll add an answer with further details that needed trial and error, but you have certainly earned that bounty. Thanks!